# Unity not rendering like hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, unity3d-shaders

I'm currently trying holotoolkit material example scene and this looks very poor in unity but great on hololens.
I found some videos displaying the same as hololens in unity.
this is how it looks in some videos in unity and on hololens 
[Other unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbLUU.png)

And this is how it is rendered in my unity
[My unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D22RM.png)

Is there anything I can do to let it be rendered like on hololens?
 Edit1: and yes, quality is set to ultra and looks fine when deployed to hololens.
Regards!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick checklist:

1. Check out [graphics emulation settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GraphicsEmulation.html) in Edit > Graphics Emulation, set to No Emulation
2. Reimport the project, pay close attention on what's written in the debug console
3. Download the project from git again, maybe try the vNext version of holotoolkit? Or if you're already on vNext, try the more stable one. Try to use a tagged release, not a development one.

Comment: even if it was my graphics card, that's a good answer, so i accept it

Answer (score 2):

Well, this was my graphics card -.-
Unity-Settings where ok

Comment: Good you've managed to find the issue, but I'm wondering - what exactly broke the rendering? Some kind of bogus drivers? It's improbable that you had a card so old that it wasn't able to render these shaders, they're DX10 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Well I didn't find out what causes the issue, tried the same project on an other computer with the same settings and it works well. I did not got it to work on my MacBook (on parallels vm and on MacOS). Tried multiple versions of unity and MixedRealityToolkit without success. But I think the Mac is using DX10, maybe I'll the a look if there is an dx11 driver available.

Comment: Mac is only supporting dx10, so this might be the problem, maybe I install windows via boot camp